# Como puedo hacer que el case me imprima solo los valores que cumplan la condicion

Tags: sql, mssql, microsoft-sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un procedimiento almacenado que me calcule una planilla , actualmente el código puede determinar los días que trabajo , años de antigüedad y según los años de antigüedad multiplicar el salario que tiene y enseñar lo que se le daría adicional por antigüedad , lo que quiero saber es porque el código me genera varios resultados cuando solo necesito los que no son Null en la columna "AdicionalPorAntiguedad".

[image: A lo que me refiero]

Me gustaría que no generara los registros NULL,
Probe solucionarlo con un group by despues de la consulta general pero al final el problema sigue siendo el mismo , porque yo no necesito que genere esos datos, como que recorre la tabla de antiguedad y para cada uno genera null.

Codigo:

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalcularDiasTrabajo]
    @FechaInicio DATE,
    @FechaFin DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiasDelMes INT

    SET @DiasDelMes = 30
    DECLARE @TotalDiasTrabajados INT




IF (MONTH(@FechaInicio) = 2 AND MONTH(@FechaFin) = 2 ) 
    BEGIN---Primer if---
        IF(DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1=28 OR DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1=29)---Si esta en febrero + los dias ingresados resultan a 28---
        BEGIN
            SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = 30
            SELECT e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
            ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario, 
            @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
            ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado
        FROM contratacion.Empleados e
        INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
        WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio;

        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1

        SELECT e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
            ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario, 
            @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
            ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado
        FROM contratacion.Empleados e
        INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
        WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio;
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN---En caso que no sea febrero---
        SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
        ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
        SELECT e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
            ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario,
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) AS Antiguedad,
            @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
            ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado,

            CASE
            ---problema aqui---
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) = pa.AñosAntiguedad 
                AND pa.AñosAntiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)
                THEN ROUND((s.Salario * pa.Porcentaje), 2)
            END AS AdicionalPorAntiguedad

            ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
        FROM contratacion.Empleados e
        INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
        LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) >= pa.AñosAntiguedad
        WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND (s.FechaFin IS NULL OR s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio)
        GROUP BY e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario, s.FechaInicio, pa.AñosAntiguedad, pa.Porcentaje
    END
END
```

Siempre estoy trabajando solo con esta seccion en el codigo:

```html
        SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
        ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
        SELECT e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
            ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario,
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) AS Antiguedad,
            @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
            ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado,

            CASE
            ---problema aqui---
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) = pa.AñosAntiguedad 
                AND pa.AñosAntiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)
                THEN ROUND((s.Salario * pa.Porcentaje), 2)
            END AS AdicionalPorAntiguedad

            ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
        FROM contratacion.Empleados e
        INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
        LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) >= pa.AñosAntiguedad
        WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND (s.FechaFin IS NULL OR s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio)
        GROUP BY e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario, s.FechaInicio, pa.AñosAntiguedad, pa.Porcentaje
```

Cualquier aclaración seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, buscando una idea para dar una solución simple, se me viene a la idea manejar el resultado en una tabla temporal, para luego aplicar *"where AdicionalPorAntiguedad IS NOT NULL"*

Ya que no tengo mas información de las tablas y su contenido, dejo el código editado para: insertar dentro de una tabla temporal la consulta realizada con un [SELECT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp), y posterior a eso, aplicar el filtro mencionado arriba a la tabla temporal

```
        SET @TotalDiasTrabajados = DATEDIFF(day, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin)+1
    ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
    
    --Se inserta el resultado del select en la tabla temporal llamada #TablaTemporal
    select * into #TablaTemporal from
    (SELECT 
        e.IdEmpleado, e.Nombres, e.Apellidos, s.TipoContrato, s.Salario,
        ROUND(s.Salario / @DiasDelMes,2) AS SalarioDiario,
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) AS Antiguedad,
        @TotalDiasTrabajados AS TotalDiasTrabajados,
        ROUND(@TotalDiasTrabajados * (s.Salario / @DiasDelMes),2) AS SalarioCalculado,

        CASE
        ---problema aqui---
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) = pa.AñosAntiguedad 
            AND pa.AñosAntiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin)
            THEN ROUND((s.Salario * pa.Porcentaje), 2)
        END AS AdicionalPorAntiguedad

        ---Seccion de cosas a hacer---
    FROM 
        contratacion.Empleados e
        INNER JOIN contratacion.Contrato s ON e.IdEmpleado = s.IdEmpleado
        LEFT JOIN  contratacion.PorcentajeAntiguedad pa ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, s.FechaInicio, @FechaFin) >= pa.AñosAntiguedad
        WHERE s.FechaInicio <= @FechaFin AND (s.FechaFin IS NULL OR s.FechaFin >= @FechaInicio)
    ) as temp --el as temp es necesario o sino no deja ejecutar

    --ahora, ya tenemos cargada la tabla temporal, y aplicamos el filtro al campo necesario
    Select * From #TablaTemporal where AdicionalPorAntiguedad is NOT NULL
    --borramos la tabla
    drop table #TablaTemporal
```

Espero esto pueda solucionar la problematica presentada